# Number of DB connectors in sqoop import

Tags: sqoop

How many database connectors are created during sqoop import and is there any maximum value is there for it ? Also, please confirm whether number of DB connectors are equal to number of mappers ?

Answer (score 0):

Number of Database connections are depended on the number of mapper (parallel task you are running) tasks are running while importing data from the database.

Suppose you have specified `-m 1` or `--num-mappers 1` in your Sqoop command, then only one database connection will be active till entire data import.

The DB number of connection or maximum values depends on allowed connection for the user through which you are accessing the database. So suppose you are accessing database with user "A" and this user has limitation to make only 10 connections, then you won't be able to open more than 10 connection at a time. It means if you specify `--num-mappers 11` in Sqoop command, your Sqoop job will fail. It means the number of DB connections is equal to the number of mappers.